# Ignore style tag on vitest coverage

Tags: vue.js, code-coverage, vitest

How to ignore the style tag to calculate the unit test coverage in a `Vue` component?

This is my `Vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="ob-card">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.ob-card {
  width: 10px;
}
</style>
```

The coverage result :

```
-----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                    |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                                                
  ObCard.vue                 |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |
```

When I remove the `<style>` tag it's `100` for every columns:

```
-----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                
  ObCard.vue                 |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |
```

Comment: Vitest's coverage report seems broken (using `c8`). I cannot even get 100% coverage with a simple text-only template, no slots or styles.

Comment: I'm asking the same question in this Vitest [discussion](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/3208) and hope to get an answer, in a plan B, you could use `/* c8 ignore start */` and stop but I hope to find a better way to ignore styling since I don't want to go add comments in every component. If you found a way to do it, please post an answer